# Does Any one got "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' " , while Loading a Keras Saved Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

After Training, I saved Both Keras whole Model and Only Weights using

```
model.save_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS) and model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

Models and Weights were saved successfully and there was no error.
I can successfully load the weights simply using model.load_weights and they are good to go, but when i try to load the save model via load_model, i am getting an error.

```
File "C:/Users/Rizwan/model_testing/model_performance.py", line 46, in <module>
Model2 = load_model('nasnet_RS2.h5',custom_objects={'euc_dist_keras': euc_dist_keras})
File "C:\Users\Rizwan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
File "C:\Users\Rizwan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 321, in _deserialize_model
optimizer_weights_group['weight_names']]
File "C:\Users\Rizwan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 320, in <listcomp>
n.decode('utf8') for n in
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I never received this error and i used to load any models successfully. I am using Keras 2.2.4 with tensorflow backend. Python 3.6.
My Code for training is :

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard, 
ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd

MODEL_NAME = "nasnet_RS2.h5"
MODEL_WEIGHTS = "nasnet_RS2_weights.h5"
def euc_dist_keras(y_true, y_pred):
return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
def main():

# Here, we initialize the "NASNetMobile" model type and customize the final 
#feature regressor layer.
# NASNet is a neural network architecture developed by Google.
# This architecture is specialized for transfer learning, and was discovered via Neural Architecture Search.
# NASNetMobile is a smaller version of NASNet.
model = NASNetMobile()
model = Model(model.input, Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='normal')(model.layers[-2].output))

#    model = load_model('current_best.hdf5', custom_objects={'euc_dist_keras': euc_dist_keras})

# This model will use the "Adam" optimizer.
model.compile("adam", euc_dist_keras)
lr_callback = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.003)
# This callback will log model stats to Tensorboard.
tb_callback = TensorBoard()
# This callback will checkpoint the best model at every epoch.
mc_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='current_best_mem3.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
es_callback=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=4, verbose=0, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)

# This is the train DataSequence.
# These are the callbacks.
#callbacks = [lr_callback, tb_callback,mc_callback]
callbacks = [lr_callback, tb_callback,es_callback]

train_pd = pd.read_csv("./train3.txt", delimiter=" ", names=["id", "label"], index_col=None)
test_pd = pd.read_csv("./val3.txt", delimiter=" ", names=["id", "label"], index_col=None)

 #    train_pd = pd.read_csv("./train2.txt",delimiter=" ",header=None,index_col=None)
 #    test_pd = pd.read_csv("./val2.txt",delimiter=" ",header=None,index_col=None)
#model.summary()
batch_size=32
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_pd, 
directory="./images", x_col="id", y_col="label",
                                              has_ext=True, 
class_mode="other", target_size=(224, 224),
                                              batch_size=batch_size)
valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_pd, directory="./images", x_col="id", y_col="label",
                                              has_ext=True, class_mode="other", target_size=(224, 224),
                                              batch_size=batch_size)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID = valid_generator.n // valid_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    epochs=20)

# we save the model.
model.save_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS)
model.save(MODEL_NAME)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # freeze_support() here if program needs to be frozen
    main()
```

Answer (score 185, accepted):

For me the solution was downgrading the `h5py` package (in my case to 2.10.0), apparently putting back only Keras and Tensorflow to the correct versions was not enough.

Comment: More on this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44467

Comment: From the link by alexhg, `We will have people working on making TF work with h5py >= 3 in the future, but this will only land in TF 2.5 or later.` This issue arises because TensorFlow can't work with h5py v3 and newer. 2.10.0 is the newest version-2.x.y.

Comment: It worked! I was trying to load a keras model in format .h5 to then save it as a tflite model.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no cp95 wheel with version 2.10.0 for Processor 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5, getting not supported error, while 3..1.0 is having the issue.

Comment: This worked for me thanks a lot!
The general rule of thumb is that check Tensorflow, Keras, or any other major library and relate with other dependencies like numpy, h5py, opencv, etc. adjust version using common sense and intuition.

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow and Keras do you need to make it work?

Answer (score 124):

I downgraded my h5py package with the following command,

```
pip install 'h5py==2.10.0' --force-reinstall
```

Restarted my ipython kernel and it worked.

Comment: Using this exact command caused an OSError due to a missing RECORD file. Using `conda install 'h5py==2.10.0'` worked though.

Comment: Key is to restart kernel.

Comment: definitely helps on google colab.

Answer (score 23):

For me it was the version of **h5py** that was superior to my previous build.
Fixed it by setting to `2.10.0`.

Answer (score 12):

Downgrade h5py package with the following command to resolve the issue,

```
pip install h5py==2.10.0 --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 6):

saved using TF format file and not h5py: save_format='tf'. In my case:

```
model.save_weights("NMT_model_weight.tf",save_format='tf')
```

Comment: `TypeError: save_weights() got an unexpected keyword argument 'save_format'`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, solved putting `compile=False` in `load_model`:

```
model_ = load_model('path to your model.h5',custom_objects={'Scale': Scale()}, compile=False)
sgd = SGD(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model_.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Why do we need `custom_objects={'Scale': Scale()}`?

Comment: Anyway, `compile = False` gives me this error, `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 229, in load_model
    model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: I have the same problem but compile=False is irrelevant :(

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to a model saved from a different version of keras. I got the same problem when loading a model generated by tensorflow.keras (which is similar to keras 2.1.6 for tf 1.12 I think) from keras 2.2.6.

You can load the weights with `model.load_weights` and resave the complete model from the keras version you want to use.

Comment: But its also happening on the same machine i used to train the model. Same error...

Comment: and yes, you are right, with `model.load_weights` i can do that, but i was wondering why i can not load the whole model architecture

Answer (score 2):

The solution than works for me was:

```
pip3 uninstall keras
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install keras
```

Answer (score 1):

I still kept having this error after having tensorflow==2.4.1, h5py==2.1.0, and python 3.8 in my environment.
what fixed it was downgrading the python version to 3.6.9

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading python, tensorflow, keras and h5py resolved the issue.

```
python -> 3.6.2

pip install tensorflow==1.3.0
pip install keras==2.1.2
pip install 'h5py==2.10.0' --force-reinstall
```