# Getting error in the CNN -- " 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to predict the label of an input image based on trained model but am getting the error of    `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` at the code below.

```
sm = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

I can not understand what is it saying and how to resolve it.

Comment: are you sure that your model is `model.h5` but `model.hdf5`

Comment: Have a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740577/does-any-one-got-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-whi)

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should *not* be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out); code here is supposed to be *minimal*, among [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That question has been refered in questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740577/does-any-one-got-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-whi

Answer (score 0):

You could follow some steps like:

1. Check your `h5py` lib version since there are some backward compatibility [issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44467).
2. Try to use explitly you model and then load its weights using `model.load_weights` function.