# How to find out which version of Keras was used for saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a saved LSTM model which I want to use. Unfortunately my foreman was kinda sloppy and didn't wrote down which version of Keras he used for training and saving the model.

Is the Keras version saved in the model? Is there a way to find out which Keras version was used for training and saving?

I get this error when I try to load it:

```
  File "/home/ebike/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 238, in load_model
    model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

As I had read on an other post there might be a issue with the `h5py` package version. How can I find out which version is the correct one for Keras 2.0.8?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: You can find the solution here without even knowing the actual complied version of the model. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740577/ https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14265